# How does a closure occur in this scheme snippet?

Tags: scheme, closures

I'm having some trouble deciphering this code snippet.

```
(define (stream n f)
    (define (next m)
        (cons m (lambda () (next (f m)))))
    (next n))
(define even (stream 0 (lambda (n) (+ n 2))))
```

I understand that 'even' is defined as a variable using the 'stream' function, which contains parameters 0 and '(lambda (n) (+ n 2))'.  Inside of 'stream', wouldn't '(next n)' indefinitely create cons nodes with a car of n + 2? Yet when I return 'even', it is a cons of (0 . # < Closure>). Could someone be so kind as to explain why this is? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Everytime `(lambda ...)` is evaluated it becomes a closure. What it means is that `f` is free and available for both procedures `next` and for the anonymous procedure it creates. `m`, which is a bound variable in `next` is also captured as a free variable in the anonymous procedure. If the language were dynamically bound none of them would exist if you called the resulting procedure in the `cdr` since the bindings would no longer exist, but since we have closures the variable exists even after the procedures that created them ended.

The pair returned by the `stream` procedure has references to the closure created when `(lambda (n) (+ n 2))` was evaluated though the name `f` even though the call is finished. Thus if you do:

```
((cdr even))            ; ==> 
(#<closure>)            ; ==> 
(cons 2 #<new-closure>) ; ==> Here
```

It's important to know that the evaluation of `next` becomes a pair with a new closure that has a new free variable `m` that is `2` this time. For each time you call the `cdr` it creates a new pair with a new closure. If it was the same each time you wouldn't have different result each iteration.

A lambda on it's own doesn't run the code in it's body. Thus instead of infinite recursion you only get one step and the result `(cons 2 #<new-closure>)`. You need to call the `cdr` of this again ni order to get one more step. etc. Likewise if I did this:

```
(define (test a)
  (define (helper b)
    (+ a b))

  helper) ; return the helper that has a as closure variable
```

Since we actually don't use the name one could just have anonymous lambda there instead of the `define` + the resulting variable. Anyway, you get something that gives you partially application:

```
((test 5) 2)  ; ==> 7

(define ten-adder (test 10))
(ten-adder 2) ; ==> 12
(ten-adder 5) ; ==> 15
```

Comment: I'm still processing all this but so far it is extremely helpful. Although I knew how lambdas worked, I completely missed the fact that it didn't run in the body, so that clears things up a bit.